# Find the equation of the tangent plane to $xy+yz+zx=11$ when $x=1$ and $y=2$

Tags: partial-derivative, surfaces, plane-geometry

> Find the equation of the tangent plane to $xy+yz+zx=11$ when $x=1$ and $y=2$ giving the answer in the form $f(x,y,z)=k$, where $k$ is a constant and $k\in \Bbb{Z}$.

So I know that the tangent plane at a given point $(a,b,f(a,b))$ is given by:
$$z=f(a,b) +(x-a)f_x(a,b)+(y-b)f_y(a,b)$$

But would someone be able to explain to me how I would go about solving this as I understand the basics of partial differentiation but not implicit partial differentiation. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is implicit partial differentiation? You are calculating the partial derivatives of $f(x,y,z)=xy+yz+zx$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation of the tangent plane to the surface $F(x,y,z) = 0$ at the point $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ is given by  $$\nabla F(x_0,y_0,z_0)\cdot\big((x,y,z) - (x_0,y_0,z_0)\big)=0$$

In your case $F(x,y,z) = xy+yz+zx-11$ so

$$\nabla F(x,y,z) = (y+z,x+z,x+y)$$

If $x_0=1$ and $y_0=2$, we have $$11 = F(x_0,y_0,z_0)=2 + 2z_0 + z_0 \implies z_0=3$$
so our point is $(x_0,y_0,z_0) = (1,2,3)$.

Hence the equation of the tangent plane is
$$0 = \nabla F(1,2,3)\cdot\big((x,y,z) - (1,2,3)\big)=(5,4,3)\cdot(x-1,y-2,z-3) = 5(x-1)+4(y-2)+3(z-3)$$
We can rewrite this as

$$5x+4y+3z=22$$

Comment: What does $\nabla F(x,y,z)$. mean notation isn't very good as I'm new to calculus really?

Comment: @H.Linkhorn It is the gradient, i.e. the vector of partial derivatives: $$\nabla F(x,y,z) = \left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}(x,y,z), \frac{\partial F}{\partial y}(x,y,z),\frac{\partial F}{\partial z}(x,y,z)\right)$$

Comment: So is it a vector that is tangent to the surface at the point?

Comment: @H.Linkhorn Actually, it is *normal* to the surface at the point. It represents the magnitude and direction of locally largest change of the function.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

If $xy+yz+zx=11$, then we can think of $z$ as a function of $x$ and $y$, namely
$$z=f(x,y)=\frac{11-xy}{x+y}$$
Now, use what you know about partial differentiation and the above formula.

Comment: Have you just factorised and rearranged for z?

Comment: Yes, we solve for $z$ the given equation:
\begin{align*}
&&xy+yz+zx&=11\\
\iff&&xy+(y+x)z&=11\\
\iff&&(y+x)z&=11-xy\\
\iff&& z&=\frac{11-xy}{x+y}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

The normal to a surface specified by an equation of the form $$f(x,y,z)=\text{constant}$$ is given by $\nabla f = \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x},\frac{\partial f}{\partial y},\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\right)$.

In this case, $\nabla f=(y+z, z+x, x+y)$. And when $x=1$ and $y=2$, $z$ is equal to $3$, so $\nabla f=(5,4,3)$.

So all you need to do is find the equation of a plane through $(1,2,3)$ and normal to $(5,4,3)$.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x,y,z):=xy+yz+zx-11=0.$

At $x=1,y=2 :$

$2+2z+z=11; z=3;$

Tangent plane passes through $(1,2,3).$

Normal to $f(x,y,z)=0:$

$\vec n= \nabla f(x,y,z)= (f_x,f_y,f_z)=$

$(y+z,x+z,x+y).$

At $(1,2,3):$ $\vec n= (5,4,3).$

Equation of plane:

$\vec n (\vec r -\vec r_0)=0;$

$(5,4,3)((x,y,z)-(1,2,3))=0;$

$5x+4y+3z -5-8-9=0;$

$5x+4y+3z=22.$